# Segmentation fault (11) when save Laravel 4.2 Eloquent model

Tags: php, apache, laravel-4, segmentation-fault, eloquent

I have a problem when I try duplicate laravel eloquent model. The model has 121 columns and I work with firebird database, apache 2.2.22, php 5.4.35 and Debian.

When save method is execute the new model is stored in database, but the redirect method is not execute and the browser display "The connection to the server was reset while the page loads." In apache logs is error "Segmentation fault (11)".

I try run this code with artisan command but still is the same error. On Windows it does not work too - cli has stopped working.

**PHP code:**

```
    $asort = Asort::on($connName)->find($asortId);

    // new ASORT_ID
    $newAsortId = DB::connection($connName)
        ->table('RDB$DATABASE')
        ->select(DB::raw('GEN_ID(SEQ_ASORT, 1) as ID'))
        ->lists('ID');

    $newAsort = new Asort;
    $newAsort = $asort->replicate();
    //$newAsort->setRawAttributes($asort->getAttributes());
    $newAsort->setConnection($connName);
    $newAsort->ASORT_ID = $newAsortId[0];
    $newAsort->ASORT_KOD = iconv("UTF-8", "CP1250", Input::get('code'));
    $newAsort->ASORT_NAZWA = iconv("UTF-8", "CP1250", Input::get('name'));
    $newAsort->ASORT_DODANO_DATACZAS = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $newAsort->ASORT_DATA_MOD = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $newAsort->save();

    return Redirect::to('route')
        ->withMessage('Message.');
```

Answer (score 0):

in congig/database.php use in connection definition array this option.
This solve same error for me in laravel 5.1

'options'   => array(
                // See [PHP/PDO MySQL drops connection if custom function used on long query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25879567/php-pdo-maysql-drops-connection-if-custom-function-used-on-long-query)
                PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
            ),

I suppose that myisam table cause the problem.